# Scrape text between <span> tags

Tags: python-3.x

I am only new to python and i am having trouble getting the text between the  tags, here is the html of the full table.

```
<div id="menu">
    <h4 style="display:none">Horse Photo</h4>
    <ul style="margin-top:5px;border-radius:6px">
        <li style="padding:0">
            <img src="/images/unknown_horse.png" style="width:298px;margin-bottom:-3px;border-radius:5px;">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <h4>Horse Profile</h4>
    <ul>
        <li>Age<span>3yo</span></li>
        <li>Foaled<span>17/11/2014</span></li>
        <li>Country<span>New Zealand</span></li>
        <li>Location<span>Kembla Grange</span></li>
        <li>Sex<span>Filly</span></li>
        <li>Colour<span>Grey</span></li>
        <li>Sire<span>Mastercraftsman</span></li>
        <li>Dam<span>In Essence</span></li>
        <li>Trainer
            <span>
                <a href="/trainer/26970-r-l-price/">R &amp; L Price</a>               
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>Earnings<span>$19,795</span></li>
    </ul>
    <h4>Owners</h4>
    <ul>
        <li style="font:normal 12px 'Tahoma">Bell View Park Stud (Mgr: A P Mackrell)</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `beautifulsoup`

Comment: Have you googled about it?

Answer (score 1):

For parsing HTML use `beautifulsoup` package. That way you can select elements of your html document with ease. To print all text within `<span>` tags, you can use this example:

```
data = """
<div id="menu">
    <h4 style="display:none">Horse Photo</h4>
    <ul style="margin-top:5px;border-radius:6px">
        <li style="padding:0">
            <img src="/images/unknown_horse.png" style="width:298px;margin-bottom:-3px;border-radius:5px;">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <h4>Horse Profile</h4>
    <ul>
        <li>Age<span>3yo</span></li>
        <li>Foaled<span>17/11/2014</span></li>
        <li>Country<span>New Zealand</span></li>
        <li>Location<span>Kembla Grange</span></li>
        <li>Sex<span>Filly</span></li>
        <li>Colour<span>Grey</span></li>
        <li>Sire<span>Mastercraftsman</span></li>
        <li>Dam<span>In Essence</span></li>
        <li>Trainer
            <span>
                <a href="/trainer/26970-r-l-price/">R &amp; L Price</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>Earnings<span>$19,795</span></li>
    </ul>
    <h4>Owners</h4>
    <ul>
        <li style="font:normal 12px 'Tahoma">Bell View Park Stud (Mgr: A P Mackrell)</li>
    </ul>
</div>
"""


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for li in soup.select('span'):
    if li.text.strip() == '':
        continue
    print(li.text)
```

Will print:

```
3yo
17/11/2014
New Zealand
Kembla Grange
Filly
Grey
Mastercraftsman
In Essence

R & L Price

$19,795
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of options to work with HTML/XML. I prefer `parsel` package. You can install it to your environment with the following command:

```
$ pip install parsel
```

After that you can use it like this:

```
from parsel import Selector
sel = Selector(html)
sel.css('ul li::text').extract()
# ['Age',
#  'Foaled',
#  'Country',
#  'Location',
#  'Sex',
#  'Colour',
#  'Sire',
#  'Dam',
#  'Trainer',
#  'Earnings',
#  'Bell View Park Stud (Mgr: A P Mackrell)']
```

More detailed description can be found [here](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html).

Comment: I will give parsel a try, yes i have googled and i have tried this.                         
 tables = soup4.find("div",{"id":"menu"})     
for table in tables:
    try:
        profiles = table.span
        for profile in profiles:
            try:
                print(profile.text)
            except:
                pass    
    except:
        pass             sorry about the formation, trying to work this place out also

Comment: @Shaun I would recommend you to read a bit more about Python. You should almost never use `except` statement without mentioning specific exceptions. And in this case I don't think these `except` statements are necessary at all.

Comment: [code]tables = soup4.find("div",{"id":"menu"})     
for table in tables:
    try:
        profiles = table.span
        for profile in profiles:
            try:
                print(profile.text)
            except:
                pass    
    except:
        pass[/code]